# Only getting a portion of JSON from website I am trying to scrape using Python, BeautifulSoup, Requests. Getting 20 responses out of 62

Tags: python, json, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, xmlhttprequest

I am trying to scrape this site for job openings:

https://recruiting.ultipro.com/UNI1029UNION/JobBoard/74c2a308-3bf1-4fb1-8a83-f92fa61499d3/?q=&o=postedDateDesc&w=&wc=&we=&wpst=

I looked in dev tools and saw that the page makes an XHR request to this site to retrieve the job opening(s) information which is in the form of a JSON object:

https://recruiting.ultipro.com/UNI1029UNION/JobBoard/74c2a308-3bf1-4fb1-8a83-f92fa61499d3/JobBoardView/LoadSearchResults

So I'm like "Great! I can parse this in two seconds using a python program like this":

'''    from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
    import json
    import requests

```
def crawl():
    union = requests.get('https://recruiting.ultipro.com/UNI1029UNION/JobBoard/74c2a308-3bf1-4fb1-8a83-f92fa61499d3/JobBoardView/LoadSearchResults').content
    soup = BeautifulSoup(union, 'html.parser')
    newDict = json.loads(str(soup))
    for job in newDict['opportunities']:
        print(job['Title'])

crawl() '''
```

Well it turns out that this page only returns 20 job openings out of 62. So I went back to the page and loaded the entirety of the page (clicked "view more opportunities")

And it said that it sent another XHR request to that same link, yet only 20 records are shown when I look.

How can I scrape all of the records from this page? And if someone could explain what is going on behind the scenes that would be great. I am a little new to web scraping so any insight is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need do a scraping , like you say the API that return all json is the link 
https://recruiting.ultipro.com/UNI1029UNION/JobBoard/74c2a308-3bf1-4fb1-8a83-f92fa61499d3/JobBoardView/LoadSearchResults  but you need set in body request this parameters

```
import requests

headers = {
    'Content-Type': 'application/json'
}

data = '{\n  "opportunitySearch": {\n    "Top": 62,\n    "Skip": 0,\n    "QueryString": "",\n    "OrderBy": [\n      {\n        "Value": "postedDateDesc",\n        "PropertyName": "PostedDate",\n        "Ascending": false\n      }\n    ],\n    "Filters": [\n      {\n        "t": "TermsSearchFilterDto",\n        "fieldName": 4,\n        "extra": null,\n        "values": [\n          \n        ]\n      },\n      {\n        "t": "TermsSearchFilterDto",\n        "fieldName": 5,\n        "extra": null,\n        "values": [\n          \n        ]\n      },\n      {\n        "t": "TermsSearchFilterDto",\n        "fieldName": 6,\n        "extra": null,\n        "values": [\n          \n        ]\n      }\n    ]\n  },\n  "matchCriteria": {\n    "PreferredJobs": [\n      \n    ],\n    "Educations": [\n      \n    ],\n    "LicenseAndCertifications": [\n      \n    ],\n    "Skills": [\n      \n    ],\n    "hasNoLicenses": false,\n    "SkippedSkills": [\n      \n    ]\n  }\n}'

response = requests.post('https://recruiting.ultipro.com/UNI1029UNION/JobBoard/74c2a308-3bf1-4fb1-8a83-f92fa61499d3/JobBoardView/LoadSearchResults', headers=headers, data=data)
print(response.text)
```

And here using pandas (pip install pandas)

```
import requests
import pandas as pd
pd.set_option('display.width', 1000)

headers = {
    'Content-Type': 'application/json'
}

data = '{\n  "opportunitySearch": {\n    "Top": 62,\n    "Skip": 0,\n    "QueryString": "",\n    "OrderBy": [\n      {\n        "Value": "postedDateDesc",\n        "PropertyName": "PostedDate",\n        "Ascending": false\n      }\n    ],\n    "Filters": [\n      {\n        "t": "TermsSearchFilterDto",\n        "fieldName": 4,\n        "extra": null,\n        "values": [\n          \n        ]\n      },\n      {\n        "t": "TermsSearchFilterDto",\n        "fieldName": 5,\n        "extra": null,\n        "values": [\n          \n        ]\n      },\n      {\n        "t": "TermsSearchFilterDto",\n        "fieldName": 6,\n        "extra": null,\n        "values": [\n          \n        ]\n      }\n    ]\n  },\n  "matchCriteria": {\n    "PreferredJobs": [\n      \n    ],\n    "Educations": [\n      \n    ],\n    "LicenseAndCertifications": [\n      \n    ],\n    "Skills": [\n      \n    ],\n    "hasNoLicenses": false,\n    "SkippedSkills": [\n      \n    ]\n  }\n}'

response = requests.post('https://recruiting.ultipro.com/UNI1029UNION/JobBoard/74c2a308-3bf1-4fb1-8a83-f92fa61499d3/JobBoardView/LoadSearchResults', headers=headers, data=data)
data=response.json()
df=pd.DataFrame.from_dict(data['opportunities'])
df= df[['Id','Title','RequisitionNumber','JobCategoryName','PostedDate']]
print(df.head(5))
```

Where data has "TOP" 62 like a limited your results:

```
{
  "opportunitySearch": {
    "Top": 62,
    "Skip": 0,
    "QueryString": "",
    "OrderBy": [
      {
        "Value": "postedDateDesc",
        "PropertyName": "PostedDate",
        "Ascending": false
      }
    ],
    "Filters": [
      {
        "t": "TermsSearchFilterDto",
        "fieldName": 4,
        "extra": null,
        "values": [

        ]
      },
      {
        "t": "TermsSearchFilterDto",
        "fieldName": 5,
        "extra": null,
        "values": [

        ]
      },
      {
        "t": "TermsSearchFilterDto",
        "fieldName": 6,
        "extra": null,
        "values": [

        ]
      }
    ]
  },
  "matchCriteria": {
    "PreferredJobs": [

    ],
    "Educations": [

    ],
    "LicenseAndCertifications": [

    ],
    "Skills": [

    ],
    "hasNoLicenses": false,
    "SkippedSkills": [

    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: Just for clarification: the answer above works well and retrieves the data. The dictionary pasted is the `body` for the XHR request - not the actual response with the desired data (the print statement can lead to confusion).